# Best choice over boost:scoped_ptr<T> pimpl

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

I'm not using boost just the standard library and I was seeing in some questions that the main difference between `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr` is that `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` is neither copyable nor movable, then I was wondering, what is the best choice over `boost::scoped_ptr<T>`? Using `std::unique_ptr` or using raw pointers with the rule of three/five in order to avoid copying and moving?

Comment: `const std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Is there a reason or you just think that it's the best option? But thanks anyhow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - You're right, I will edit.

Comment: you never want to manage raw pointers, so `unique_ptr` is the only sensible option. adding `const` will make it non-movable, like `scoped_ptr`

Comment: @BryanChen:  You get more points if you create an answer rather than an excellent comment. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use `const std::unique_ptr`.

You almost never want to manage raw pointers directly so `unique_ptr` is the only sensible option (`shared_ptr` isn't suitable for pimpl, rarely you want to share the impl object). Adding `const` will make it non-movable, like `scoped_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little ambiguous, but the answer is very definitively that you should use either a std::unique_ptr or a std::shared_ptr to hold your pimpl, depending on whether you want your class to share state (shared_ptr) or have exclusive access with the benefit of being automatically moveable (unique_ptr).

Management of naked pointers is extremely difficult to get right, impossible if you manage more than one in the same class. unique_ptr was created to help you write flawless programs with ease.

You would be wise to use it.

Comment: _"Management of naked pointers is extremely difficult to get right, impossible if you manage more than one in the same class."_ The first claim is scaremongering and the second is downright wrong, and clearly so at that. I don't recommend management of naked pointers to anybody but these claims are just fallacious as far as I can tell.

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit. The rule of three as I put in the question is the easiest way I see to handle a raw pointer in a class judging that it's not going to be shared, then we have a perfect definition of ownership. And talking about pimpl idiom the instantiation stay within the class, nothing of dependency injection or passing the pointer as an argument.
But I'm going to use `std::unique_ptr` that leaves it clearer about the ownership and to avoid more code (and headaches).

Comment: the number of people capable of writing correct, exception-safe code when managing raw pointers is vanishingly small. ignore the indignation. use the managed pointers.

Comment: There's nothing to worry about @RichardHodges, I respect your opinion and I agree that the number of people capable of doing that is really small but well, still people that can do, and still people that can learn how to do, that is why we are here.

Comment: "Indignation" what the hell? You're going around _lying_ to people in order to support your suggestions (the suggestions themselves are sound) and accusing _me_ of less than honourable behaviour when I point it out??

Comment: ok, let's replace the word "impossible" with the phrase "so close to impossible for the vast majority of unfortunate souls who will modify and maintain your code in the future that we may as well consider it impossible and not attempt to do it."
@LightnessRacesinOrbit I have no doubt that you are able to correctly form an assignment operator for a class that maintains two or more objects which have been allocated with `new`. I also have no doubt that you would be displeased to have to encounter someone else's attempt to do so in production code. :-)